# else statement only works when I add a return or break

Tags: c#

My else statement only works when I add a break or return, and I have been trying to fix this for 3 hours and I have no clue what I am doing. I don't need you to rewrite the code just please tell me what to do.

```
    while (pHealth > 0 || pHappiness > 0 && !restarted)
    {
        Console.Clear();

        UpdateHud();

        // Get user input

        Console.Write("╚═ENTER CHOICE: ");
        choice = Console.ReadLine();

        // Add your Codes here!

        if (choice == "A" || choice == "a")
        {
            if (pHappiness > 0)
            {
                pHealth = pHealth + 10;
                pHappiness = Math.Clamp(pHappiness - 25, 0, 100);
            }
        }
        else if (choice == "B" || choice == "b")
        {
            if (pHealth > 0)
            {
                pHealth = Math.Clamp(pHealth - 25, 0, 100);
                pHappiness = pHappiness + 15;
            }
        }
        else if (choice == "C" || choice == "c")
        {
            if (pHappiness > 0)
            {
                pHealth = pHealth + 20;
                pHappiness = Math.Clamp(pHappiness - 40, 0, 100);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Clear();
            UpdateHud();
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid!!!");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more of your code (what's happening before the `else` statement)? That helps us understand the context.

Comment: context? I assure you, `else` works just fine; can we see enough code to repro what you're seeing? ideally with the `break` that you're adding that fixes it? presumably it is inside a `foreach`/`switch`, but can we see what you mean please?

Comment: This would be a good time to [learn how to use the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) so you can step through your code to see what's happening.

Comment: Maybe you simply need to update `pHealth` and/or `pHappiness` inside your `else` statement, so that the `while` loop won't continue being executed afterwards?

Comment: Also, your `while` loop condition may need a pair of extra parentheses, i.e.: `while ((pHealth > 0 || pHappiness > 0) && !restarted)` -- that way, the `while` loop will be executed if `restarted == false` AND [either `pHealth > 0` or `pHappiness > 0`].

Answer (score 0):

Remove 2nd while outside of 1st while loop. Your game over logs are written ih happiness or health are equal to zero, but parent loop is executed while they are greater than zero. Maybe that solve problem. And reconsider refactoring to use switch instead so many if else.

Comment: thanks but if the health or happiness turns zero it doesn't show the game over

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).